# Adding fields and variables into a Signup form

Tags: php, mysql, sql

it's been 10+ years I learned PHP, HTML, SQL and CSS. I have a hard time adapting that template to include other information into the registration form. Nothing really new here but it seems the process dont go through the error variables validation just before sending the SQL command to the DB.

```
    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err) && empty($lastname_err) && empty($language_err) && empty($firstname_err)){
        
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, firstname, lastname, language) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
         
        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $param_username, $param_password, $param_firstname, $param_lastname, $param_language);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
            $param_firstname = $firstname;
            $param_lastname = $lastname;
            $param_language = $language;

    echo "param_username :" , $param_username, " param_firstname :", $param_firstname, " param_language :", $param_language, " param_lastname :", $param_lastname , " param_password :", $param_password;


            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: login-oo-format.php");
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            $stmt->close();
        }
        // Close connection
    $mysqli->close();
```

Even if i add an Echo after the first "if" it doesnt work. I can't figure out where the issue is. Nevertheless I did a Echo $username_err, and for all the other _err variables, they're all empty.

Here below one of the field validation

```
    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
    } elseif(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/', trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Username can only contain letters, numbers, and underscores.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        
        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $param_username);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                // store result
                $stmt->store_result();

                if($stmt->num_rows == 1){
                    $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                } else{
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
```

The original template came from here https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php

Here is the HMTL Form part

```
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="margin-top:5%;margin-bottom:5%;">
        <table><td class="login" style="border:1px solid black;padding:20px;background-color:rgba(232,183,138, 0.15);">
            <h2>Sign Up</h2>
                <p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Prefered language</label>                
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="language" id="french" value="french" checked>
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="french">
                        Français / French
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="language" id="english" value="english">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="english">
                        English / Anglais
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $language_err; ?></span>
                <hr>    
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>First name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($firstname_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>">
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $firstname_err; ?></span>
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Last name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($lastname_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>">
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $lastname_err; ?></span>
                    <hr>
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
                </div>    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
                    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating input-group mb-3" style="margin-top:5%;">
                    <div class=" form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btngreen-color" value="Submit">
                    <input type="reset" class="btn btnbrown-color" value="Reset">
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <p><b>Already have an account?</b> <a href="login-oo-format.php" style="color:black;">Login here</a>.</p>
            </form>
        </td></table>
    </div>
```

**EDIT : I passed the first _err validation if condition. Now it seem to be stuck at the next condition " if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql))" with error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindparam() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\register-oo-format.php:180 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\register-oo-format.php on line 180"**

Comment: Please could you help us understand what you're trying to add to the code.  Also could you give a clear description of what you expect to happen versus what is actually happening.

Comment: so you get any error or not even get inside the IF case? Where is your registration form and how you send the data to your PHP?

Comment: The username, password and confirm password were the only 3 fields. I added first name, last name and language fields. Sadly everything seems to work until the last if that verify if all the _err variables are empty before continuing with the SQL statement.

Comment: @Andy I added more information at my initial question. Hope it could help

Comment: @AngelDeykov I am able to "Echo" all the _err variables value before the if condition. They all are empty when all fields in the form are filled. But I can't get pass the If condition... I can't find out why :/

Comment: Looking at the error there does not seem to be an underscore in "bind_param" (you're calling "mysqli_stmt::bindparam()")... could you double check that you haven't changed this (it's correct in the code snippet you include) https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php ... the PDO version is capitalized https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: @Andy I tried both. Still I get the following error : "Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: The number of elements in the type definition string must match the number of bind variables in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\register-oo-format.php:178 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\register-oo-format.php(178): mysqli_stmt->bind_param('gagno5482', NULL, 'Francis', 'Gagnon', 'french') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\register-oo-format.php on line 178"

Comment: You are only binding two parameters ---> `$stmt->bind_param("ss",`  You'll need to bind a parameter for every ? in your sql statement

Comment: Hi @Andy I added more afterward. I just have to write "sssss" for 5 parameters, right ?

Comment: Please see a **correct** [INSERT query example](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/insert). It should be much simple that that ziggurat of code you currently have